# session management using filters

Tags: java, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I am working on session management using filters i have written method and using managedbean annotation i'm trying to send the validation success to filter .

```
@ManagedBean(name = "customer")
@SessionScoped
public class CustomerBean implements Serializable{


    public String checkValidCustomer(){
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
         HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        cust.setUsername(getUsername());
        cust.setPassword(getPassword());
        String returnValue = customerBo.checkValidCustomer(cust); 
        if(returnValue == "success"){
        session.setAttribute("customer", returnValue);
        }
        else
        {
            session.setAttribute("customer", null);
        }
        return returnValue;
```

and i'm getting succes in retunValue string so i tried to pass as value to managedBean annotation .and myfilter code is like.

```
@WebFilter("/faces/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String cust = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute("customer");
        if (cust != null && cust.equals("success")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/default.xhtml");
        }
    }
```

I'm getting null value for String cust and when i open the page for login it shows This webpage has a redirect loop.Can you please tell where i'm doing wrong..

Comment: Try to bear with the fact that `"success" == "success"` is `false` before proceeding with JSF. Stick to `equals` instead. And, yes, using a debugger on your own will almost always give you guidance on how to correct your code, or at least on what's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
          HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
          System.out.println("Inside the filter.............."  );
          HttpSession session = request.getSession();
          User u = null;
          if(session.getAttribute("customer")!=null){
              u = (User) session.getAttribute("customer");
          }       
          if (u!= null)
          {
              System.out.println("user does exits.." + u.getUname() );// u can see who was logged here
              chain.doFilter(req, resp);          
          }else{
              System.out.println("user does exits..");        
          }
```